# I know the values of $P(A)$, $P(B)$, and $P(A \cup B)$, is this enough to find $P(A^c \mid B^c)$?

Tags: probability, self-study, conditional-probability

$$ P(A) = .72, \qquad
P(B) = .6, \qquad
P(A \cup B) = .9 $$

I've tried to reason through this, but I don't know how to work out the conditional probability of complements $P(A^c \cap B^c)$. The farthest I got was this conditional probability $P(A \mid B)$.

Comment: @Tim I'm looking for a pointer in the direction of how to apply the complements rule in reasoning through to the conditional probability I'm searching for. I don't need the answer nor do I want it, just a hint, after having stared at this issue for over an hour.

Comment: Yes, I used it to indicate the complement. Is there a notation that's preferred on Cross Validated?

Comment: The usual notation is $P(\neg A)$ which you get with `P(\neg A)`.

Comment: By far the most common notation is $A^c$ for the complement of the event $A$.  I hope you don't mind me editing the post to avoid confusion.

Comment: does this help?  $P(\neg A | \neg B) \cdot P(\neg B) = P( \neg A \neg B)$
if you're already there, do you know how $P( \neg A \neg B)$ relates to $P( A \cup B)$?

Comment: @gopher The <whatever>$^c$ notation for <whatever>-complement is perfectly valid and widely enough used that it should be understood by anyone that has read more than one or two books on the subject. I think it would be ridiculous to impose one single notation when there are many in use. If I recall correctly there are at least five notations for complements. There's *no need whatever* to change it, though - as usual with notations that vary from book to book and course to course - it's best to define your notation in your question.

Answer (score 3):

Remember DeMorgan's laws.  Namely, $A \cup B = (A^c \cap B^c)^c$ and so $P(A \cup B) = 1 - P(A^c \cap B^c)$.